# 23 часа(,) 56 минут(,) 4 секунды

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Нужно ли разделять запятой?

***23 часа(,) 56 минут(,) 4 секунды.***

И можно записать так: ***23:56:04***? Или так: ***23/56/04***?

Лично мне кажется, что никаких запятых ставить не нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

• Правильно так (о времени):
**23 часа 56 минут 4 секунды** (без запятых) или **23:56:04** (через двоеточие).

> ...между числами стандарт требует ставить двоеточие: 23:30:10 (23 часа 30 минут 10 секунд).

*На часах было 23 часа 45 минут* (И. Н. Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский).
*В 23 часа 51 минуту 06 секунд последовал торжественный доклад...* (Б. Е. Черток. Ракеты и люди).

• О временно́м промежутке (длительности) правильно так (тоже без запятых):
[Потребовалось, использовано, длилось] 23 часа 56 минут 4 секунды.

*Первый полет, совершенный в 1988–1989 годах, продолжался 240 суток 23 часа 35 минут 49 секунд* (Л. Смиренный. Весомая невесомость).

[Как правильно написать время](http://ktvd.ru/kak-pravilno-napisat-vremja/)
[Время в научно-технических документах](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/)

Comment: Мы продолжим разговор, Рим? Жду уже давно.